# How to remove labels from below only at small resolutions chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/bjvVyr

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
data: {
  labels: ['January 01', 'February', 'March 02', 'April', 'May 03'],
  datasets: [{ 
      data: [2,5,3,12,17],
      label: "2017",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderColor: "blue",
      fill: false
    }, { 
      data: [10,12,21,22,34],
      label: "2018",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderColor: "red",
      fill: false
    }
  ]
},
  options: {}
});
```

Is it possible to remove labels with mounth on amalenkie permissions of devices? Is this possible in chart.js?

Comment: You want to remove those month labels (like 'January 01', etc.) from chart.js display?

Comment: @Pranay, yes...

Comment: labels: ['', '', '', '', ''], this is not helping? If you want dynamically handle that, you need to inject blanks in labels array as per datasets.data

Comment: @Pranay, I need hide this labels only small (<480px) devices. But on large screen show this labels